# Creating a readable FxCop report

Tags: c#, .net, fxcop

Is there a good tool that can convert the XML output of FxCop into something that can be put into a Word document?  I'd prefer not to write an XML-FO XSLT transform, maybe someone did something like that already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can simply copy and paste into a spreadsheet and paste that into Word.

Comment: Select all of the lines in the grid inside FxCop itself and copy it onto clipboard.

Answer (score 9):

Somebody did.  You'll find several .xsl files in the Xml subdirectory of the FxCop install directory.

- FxCopReport.xsl
- FxCopRichConsoleOutput.xsl
- VSConsoleOutput.xsl

Answer (score 2):

Following worked better for me.

1. select all the lines in the grid,
2. do a right click, Copy as , CSV.

Go to excel and import the text as comma separated content.